# Multiple If statements Cognos RS 10

Tags: if-statement, cognos

In Cognos RS 10, I am trying to create multiple if statements but the report fails. The report works when I do not have this in as an expression.

I want to create a field that shows days between RUN date and Received date when Status Classification = 'Open' and when it = 'Pend'.

I want to create a field that shows days between CLOSED date and Received date when Status Classification = 'Closed'

Can someone offer some help? The expression validates but the report fails. Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is what I'm using:

```
**If ([CS].[Status Classification]  = 'Open') THEN
(_days_between ([Run Date] , [CS].[Received Date]))
else IF ([CS].[Status Classification] = 'Pend') THEN
(_days_between ([Run Date] , [CS].[Received Date]))
else IF ([CS].[Status Classification]  = 'Closed') THEN
(_days_between([CS].[Closed Date Time] , [CS].[Received Date]))
ELSE
null**
```

Comment: What is the error you get? What is the DB you work with? Is it relational or DMR? Dynamic or compatible query mode?

Comment: I figured it out. The error was because of too much data pulling. I had too many data items in my query. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use brackets around each if, so it'll be like:

IF (condition) THEN (expression)
ELSE 
(
IF (condition) THEN (expression)
ELSE (expression)
)

or use case expression.

case (expression)
when () then ()
else ()
end